# How to consistently get golden beads on meringue topping?

Tags: cheesecake, meringue

Sometimes, golden beads form on my cheesecake with meringue topping. I very much like this effect, but I can't get it to appear consistently. Can anyone give advice as to what to pay attention to?

Comment: Funny, that's not usually desired. Related (although opposite): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37486/my-meringue-forms-syrup-beads-on-top/37488#37488

Comment: @Jolenealaska I had no idea how the effect was called and was unable to Google it, and came to the same conclusion. The first time I made the cake, it turned out [looking something like this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tm0CnKAUnt0/TyX-T9TKvRI/AAAAAAAAAq4/nXKqTNiwxCc/s1600/Weeping+Lemon+Meringue.JPG), but the pecks were even smaller and more numerous which I think looked quite nice. Since being able to Google it, I found some other [not so great examples](http://i708.photobucket.com/albums/ww88/TheChickenLady/CoconutCreamPie001.jpg) where it does look undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's your meringue weeping. You could either make a very unstable meringue, which will weep uncontrollably, or you can replicate the effect with caramelised sugar - the latter is probably better for consistency and not-having-a-sloppy-mess-on-top-of-your-cheesecakeness.

Comment: Awww... sad meringues weeping uncontrollably...

Comment: I was going to say weep like a Brazilian football supporter but I thought that might be too harsh...

Comment: So, that would imply I almost always make an "unstable meringue". Could you explain what to pay attention to to not have that happen?

Comment: Add the sugar to the egg whites gradually (1 teaspoon or so at a time). You can also add 1tsp of white wine vinegar or a little cream of tartar.

Comment: Hmm I did add it gradually, but more than a teaspoon at a time. The recipe called for 5 egg whites and 75g of sugar.