# What's this odd stuff coming out of my meringue?

Tags: meringue

[image]

I used this (http://m.allrecipes.com/recipe/58871/authentic-french-meringues/) recipe, but added some vanilla, probably a bit extra sugar, and baked them at 185 instead of 200 with the door open.

Comment: That is odd and extreme for this, but I'm still going to bet on "weeping", http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37486/my-meringue-forms-syrup-beads-on-top/37488#37488 or a very related phenomenon.

Comment: Hi keroro, and welcome! Our users need some reputation before they can put an image inline in a post. I edited the question for you so the image is visible, after a few upvotes you'll get the ability to do it yourself for the next time you need it.

Comment: Run.  Just run...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely egg white seepage, by the looks of the shape of it you've either over whipped the egg whites OR let them sit for too long before cooking which meant they spilt slightly before going in the oven.

Another possibility is the oven wasn't hot enough to begin with OR the environment (kitchen) was too warm.

When ever I've cooked meringue I've had the oven on 180 for 10min then turned it off and left the meringue in undisturbed over night. Never had any issue's that way. The only time I've had seepage is when I've beaten my eggs then got disturbed by a check coming on and having to leave the whites for 5-10min before shaping and cooking...

Comment: 180c or 180f ? I assume celsius, but whenever I've tried that it overcooked/burnt the meringue. Did you use a fan oven?

Comment: Yep, 180c and a fan oven. It would possibly depend on how many and how large your meringues were. In my answer, I was talking about meringues around 3 inch across and around 2 inch high. With ~24 in the oven at one time. Hope that helps.